# Schema generation using Hibernate Vs Manual schema generation

Tags: sql, hibernate

I have worked on projects that involved creation of schema by hand coding sql scripts.  Then we have used hibernate to do DML related activites.

Now, I am starting a project that involves extensive database entities creation and I was wondering if it is a good idea to use Hibernate itself to generate the entities.  In other words, is hibernate capable of handling all possible DDL related scenarios, especially the ones that are complex in nature.  Or, is it advisable to hand code the DDL sql scripts and use Hibernate for DML related tasks.

Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Hibernate isn't able to handle all possible situations (synonyms, tablespaces, and all sorts of various things can't be handled by Hibernate).

I would only consider using Hibernate (to handle the schema creation and updates) for a quick and dirty POC. Otherwise, SQL scripts or Liquibase are your friends. You'll need them once you have a database in production that you need to migrate anyway.

Comment: This makes sense, will go with external schema design and sql generation and use Hibernate for DML related changes, as always.  Thank you!